# Accessing Python dict values with the key start characters

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering: would it be possible to access dict values with uncomplete keys (as long as there are not more than one entry for a given string)? For example:

```
my_dict = {'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july'}
print my_dict['Date']
>> '15th july'
```

Is this possible? How could it be done?

Comment: you need languages like PERL or ML for this, as a built-in feature.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such feature in Perl.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can't do such directly with `dict[keyword]`. You have to iterate through the `dict` and match each key against the keyword and return the corresponding value if the keyword is found.
This is going to be an `O(N)` operation.

```
>>> my_dict = {'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july'}
>>> next(v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k)
'15th july'
```

To get all such values use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [ v for k, v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k]
['15th july']
```

use `str.startswith` if you want only those values whose keys starts with 'Date':

```
>>> next( v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k.startswith('Date'))
'15th july'
>>> [ v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k.startswith('Date')]
['15th july']
```

Answer (score 10):

not the best solution, can be improved (overide **getitem**)

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        keys = [k for k in self.keys() if value in k]
        key = keys[0] if keys else None
        return self.get(key)


my_dict = mydict({'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july'})
print(my_dict['Date'])# returns 15th july
```

Comment: nice thought : might also be adjusted to use a regex pattern

Answer (score 7):

Sure it is possible:

```
print next(val for key, val in my_dict.iteritems() if key.startswith('Date'))
```

but this incurs a full scan through the dictionary. It only finds the *first* such matching key (where 'first' is arbitrary) and raises `StopIteration` instead of `KeyError` if no keys match.

To get closer to what you are thinking of, it's better to write this as a function:

```
def value_by_key_prefix(d, partial):
    matches = [val for key, val in d.iteritems() if key.startswith(partial)]
    if not matches:
        raise KeyError(partial)
    if len(matches) > 1:
        raise ValueError('{} matches more than one key'.format(partial))
    return matches[0]
```

Comment: To get even closer, you may want to subclass `dict` with that function. Or better, reimplement it using a tree instead of a hash.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built-in filter function to filter dictionaries, lists, etc. based on specific conditions.

```
filtered_dict = dict(filter(lambda item: "Date" in item[0], my_dict.items()))
```

The advantage is that you can use it for different data structures.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> my_dict = {'name': 'Klauss', 'age': 26, 'Date of birth': '15th july'}
>>> next(v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k)
'15th july'


>>> [ v for k,v in my_dict.items() if 'Date' in k]
['15th july']


>>> next( v for k,v in my_dict.items() if k.startswith('Date'))
'15th july'
>>> [ v for k,v in my_dict.items() if k.startswith('Date')]
['15th july']
```

if i use the above given method i am getting StopIteration exception

Answer (score 2):

You are not suggesting a coherent API:

1. What should be the result of `my_dict['']`? You don't have a one-to-one mapping.
2. How is it supposed to be extended to types other than `str`?

Another reason you can't have it directly, even for strings and assuming you always return a list, is because Python's `dict` is implemented using a hash table, and it will map `xy` and `xz` to unrelated cells in the table.

So, going the other way: such a lookup to would mean going for a slower implementation of `dict`, (which doesn't make sense, optimizing for an uncommon use) or being as slower as a full scan - which you may as well write it by hand, as it is not *that* common to be worth a dedicated convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice and clever implementation of a 'fuzzy' dictionary in pywinauto - this might be perfect for what you need here.

https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/source/browse/pywinauto/fuzzydict.py

and docs here:
http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.fuzzydict.html

(edit: although if you specifically want to match from the beginning of the key, you might need to replace SequenceMatcher logic with your custom code)