# Python dictionary vague key search

Tags: python, dictionary, search

I was wondering if there's way that I can do a "vague" key search in python dictionary. For example, I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = { "Google.com" : value1, "StackOverFlow": value2, ....}
```

if I have a string

```
name= "Google" or name = "google" or even name = "gooogle"
```

and I want to access the value1(whose key is "Google.com") in my dictionary, how do I do that? I know I can iterate through the keys list and do some string processing but if I have multiple names that I wanna do such vague search, it's gonna be O(n^2) right? Is there any efficient way to do that? Suppose the data dictionary is very very large.

Hope my question is clear...

Comment: 1. You're looking for *"fuzzy search"*. 2. Yes that's going to be pretty inefficient, you're not getting the most out of a dictionary if you can't rely on exact key hash matches.

Comment: If you have `google.com` and `Google.com` what should `oogle.com` match?

Comment: There was a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106819/accessing-python-dict-values-with-the-key-start-characters and it pointed to an implementation: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/5176a9eaf568781a0cb8700dd020ab8753592e61/pywinauto/fuzzydict.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do some fuzzy searching then you'll effectively have to come up with your own hashing algorithm. Or create your own variant of a dictionary and just override the `.__getitem__` and associated methods.

Here is an example:

```
from jellyfish import soundex

data = {soundex('google'): 'google.com', soundex('stackoverflow'): 'stackoverflow.com'}
print(data[soundex('gooooogle')])
# Should print `google.com`, because soundex pretty much ignores vowels
```

Or the alternative:

```
from jellyfish import soundex

class SoundexDict(dict):
    # __init__ and __repr__ is left as an exercise for the reader
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(soundex(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(soundex(key), value)

mydict = SoundexDict()
mydict['google'] = 'google.com'
print(mydict['gewgle'])  # prints 'google.com'
```

Comment: It seems illegal to populate the data dictionary with such syntax: data[soundex(name)]

Comment: I mean, I'm getting TypeError: expected unicode, got str

Comment: You're probably using Python2. You'll probably need to use `mydict[u'google'] = 'google.com'`, or adjust the setters to do `soundex(key.encode())` or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient vague key as you search. Python's dict uses hashes to find the place in the dictionary, and hashes are pretty different for similar strings. Let's see:

```
assert hash("Google.com") == 4399753695393964520
assert hash("Google.co") == -9213236188503134626
```

At least in my OS.

Conclusion: You will rarely get "near" the desired value by using similar keys.

So: no. You cannot avoid O(n^2) using dicts.