# Why is not my code working while extracting values from dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I went through the link [Accessing Python dict values with the key start characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106819/accessing-python-dict-values-with-the-key-start-characters)

```
my = [{'k1': 'a','k2': '1234','k3':'12'},
    {'k1': 'a','k2': '1295','k3':'12'}]

for i in my:
    #print ([ v for k,v in i.items() if str(v).startswith('12')])
    print ([ v for k,v in i.items() if i['k2'].startswith('12')])
```

My out

```
['a', '1234', '12']
['a', '1295', '12874']
```

Expected

```
['1234']
['1295']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the outer list and use a list comprehension:

```
my = [{'k1': 'a','k2': '1234','k3':'12'},
    {'k1': 'a','k2': '1295','k3':'12'}]

print([x['k2'] for x in my if x['k2'].startswith('12')])
```

The problem with the original code is an extra traversal over all of the entries in `i` if it has a key `'k2'` with a value starting with `'12'`. It could be written as:

```
for i in my:
    if i['k2'].startswith('12'):
        print(i['k2'])
```

Note that the code raises a `KeyError` if `'k2'` doesn't exist on one of the dicts, so you can use

```
[x['k2'] for x in my if 'k2' in x and x['k2'].startswith('12')]
```

if you anticipate this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You get that result because the condition `i['k2'].startswith('12')` always returns `True`. (either `i['k2']='1234'` or `i['k2']='1295'`) so all the values are taken.